# tifffile で 16bit の TIFF 画像を読もうとすると "cannot decompress PACKBITS" エラーになる

Tags: python, centos, 画像

Pythonで16bitのtiff画像を読み込みたいです。そこで，tifffileパッケージを用いて以下のコードで画像の読み込みを行いました。

```
import tifffile
PATH = "/mnt/dataDrive/image/3/2020_1_10/2_32_39_depthfield.tiff"
img = tifffile.imread(PATH)
```

Pythonのバージョンは3.6.8でCentOS7を使っています。
しかし，以下のようなエラーが出てきました。

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-56c32408d22b> in <module>
      1 import tifffile
      2 PATH = "/mnt/dataDrive/image/3/2020_1_10/2_32_39_depthfield.tiff"
----> 3 img = tifffile.imread(PATH)

/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tifffile/tifffile.py in imread(files, **kwargs)
    714     if isinstance(files, basestring) or hasattr(files, 'seek'):
    715         with TiffFile(files, **kwargs_file) as tif:
--> 716             return tif.asarray(**kwargs)
    717     else:
    718         with TiffSequence(files, **kwargs_seq) as imseq:

/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tifffile/tifffile.py in asarray(self, key, series, out, validate, maxworkers)
   2411         elif len(pages) == 1:
   2412             result = pages[0].asarray(out=out, validate=validate,
-> 2413                                       maxworkers=maxworkers)
   2414         else:
   2415             result = stack_pages(pages, out=out, maxworkers=maxworkers)

/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tifffile/tifffile.py in asarray(self, out, squeeze, lock, reopen, maxsize, maxworkers, validate)
   4355             if self.compression not in TIFF.DECOMPESSORS:
   4356                 raise ValueError('TiffPage %i: cannot decompress %s'
-> 4357                                  % (self.index, self.compression.name))
   4358             if 'SampleFormat' in tags:
   4359                 tag = tags['SampleFormat']

ValueError: TiffPage 0: cannot decompress PACKBITS
```

どのように解決すればよいのか教えて頂きたいです。
また，別の手法がありましたらそちらを教えて頂きたいです。
ただし，読み込んだ際に8bit画像になってしまうようなものは避けたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: エラーメッセージ的には「[PackBits圧縮アルゴリズム](https://bb.watch.impress.co.jp/cda/bbword/15780.html)未対応のためデコードできない」と言っている風です。[tifffileライブラリ](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/) 2020.5.30 で "Re-add pure Python PackBits decoder." とあるため、これ以降のバージョンにアップデートできれば取り扱えるかもしれませんね。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。tifffileを最新版にしましたが改善されませんでした，，，

Comment: この記事 [Python and 16 Bit Tiff](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7247371/9014308) にある [pearu/pylibtiff](https://github.com/pearu/pylibtiff) あたりがサポートしてるかも。[libtiff](http://www.libtiff.org/man/libtiff.3t.html) に`PackBits compression (32773)`とあったりするので。あるいはその記事やこちらの記事 [Python: Read and write TIFF 16 bit , three channel , colour images](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18446804/9014308) のライブラリ等も試してみてはどうでしょう？